# Why do I get error in JS script?

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

I'm running a JS script, **which is correct** but I get an error when running in Nashorn.
 Why is this error? 
When only compiled the JS and out of Nashorn, it runs correctly and no errors are displayed but this only occurs in Nashorn.

JS

```
function process(val) {
    var isPeso = "(?:k|m|g)b$";
    var normalizado = val.trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
    var unidade = "";
    var numberPattern = /\d+(\.\d{1,2})?|(Livre)/i;
    var myArray = [];
    if(isPeso.test(myArray)) {
        myArray = normalizado.match(isPeso);
    }
    if (myArray != null) {
        unidade = myArray;
        var i;
        var valores = [];

        if(numberPattern.test(val)) {
            var getNumbers = val.match(numberPattern);

            for (i = 0; i < getNumbers.length - 1; i++) {
                valores.push(getNumbers[i]);
            }
        }
        var out = "";
        //Caso [X ou superior]
        if (normalizado.indexOf("superior") > -1) {
            return valores[0] + unidade + " ou superior";
        }
        //Caso [X até Y] e [até Y]
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("até") > -1) {
            //Caso [até Y]
            if (valores.length == 1) {
                out = "até " + valores[0];
            }
            //Caso [X até Y]
            else {
                out = valores[0] + " até " + valores[1];
            }
        }

        //Caso [X ou Y] ou [X ou Y ou ...]
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("ou") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("/") > -1) {
            out = valores[0];
            for (i = 1; i < valores.length - 1; i++) {
                out += valores[i];
            }
        }
        //Caso livre
        else if (normalizado.indexOf("*") > -1 || normalizado.indexOf("livre") > -1) {
            out = "Livre";
        }
        //Caso X
        else {
            if (valores.length > 0) {
                out = valores[0];
            }
        }
        if (out.length == 0 || out == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return out + unidade;
    }
}
```

Log

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: (?:k|m|g)b$ has no such function "test" in <eval> at line number 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That string is not a valid regex and your array is empty so the test will return false. Here is a valid version:

```
var isPeso = /(?:k|m|g)b$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [regexp](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) pattern is not valid, you are missing `/` characters:

```
var isPeso = /(?:k|m|g)b$/;
```

As a **tip**, you could add a function to String prototype, so that you could write contains method instead of checking `indexOf`

```
String.prototype.contains = function(input) { return this.indexOf(input) != -1; };
```

This should meke your code more readable.

@mplungjan has beaten me in time response:)